# Macro not working when the file is unshared and share again

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to add a couple of simple macros to a file that is a shared excel binary workbook. The problem whenever the file is unshared the macro does not work anymore. The code is as following:

```
    Sub uploadMain()

Dim xlsFile As String                
Dim wbResults As Workbook           
Dim wbmCall As Workbook            
Dim agmtCdCell As Range
Dim amtCldCell As Range
Dim srchRange As Integer
Dim callClmn As Integer
Dim srchString As String
Dim callAmt As String
Dim notFound As String
Dim lastRowNo As Long
Dim srchRowNo As Long
Dim srcRowNo As Long
Dim customView As Boolean           
Dim amntReplaced As Boolean       
Dim asset_column As Integer 
Dim typ
Dim quantity_column As Integer
Dim quantity As Variant
Dim unique_identifier As Integer
Dim lastrow_updated As Integer 
Dim lastrow_preupload As Integer 
Dim wiersz
Dim asset As String
Dim state As String
Dim old_row As Integer
Dim amp As String
Dim loaded
Dim direction_column As Integer
Dim delivery_type As String


    Sheets("Calls").Select

    ThisWorkbook.Save
    
    customView = False

    amntReplaced = False   

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbmCall = ThisWorkbook
    
    asset_column = Cells.Find(What:="Asset", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False).Column
    quantity_column = Cells.Find(What:="Quantity", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False).Column

    srchRange = Cells.Find(What:="Agmt Code", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False).Column
                
    direction_column = Cells.Find(What:="Direction", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False).Column
    
    
    xlsFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Workbooks (*.xls; *.xlsx),*.xls;*.xslx", , "Select Acadia extract to import.", , False)
    If xlsFile = "False" Then Exit Sub
    
    Set wbResults = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xlsFile, UpdateLinks:=0)

    
    ' call amtcalled removed
    
Dim relocList() As Variant
Dim lngPosition As Integer
Dim startingRow As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim temporary_row As Integer

wbmCall.Activate
Dim b As Integer

    Sheets("AcadiaFeeds").Select

    Dim amp_array() 
    If Range("J65536").End(xlUp).Row > 2 Then
    
        Cells(Range("J65536").End(xlUp).Row, 10).Select 'last row

        lastrow_preupload = Range("J65536").End(xlUp).Row
        
        amp_array = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp))
        
    End If
wbResults.Activate

'________________

For i = 2 To lastrow_preupload
    If Range("Z" & i).Value = "Deliver" Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Select
    Selection.Replace What:="GROSS", Replacement:="OTM", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Select
    Selection.Replace What:="GROSS", Replacement:="ITM", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    End If
Next i
'_______________________


relocList = Array("Margin Call Amp ID", "Delivery Type", "Amp ID", "Call Type", "Business State", "Valuation Date", "Total Call Amount", "Our Unique Agreement Identifier", "Quantity", "FX Currency", "Security Id", "Type")
Stop
For lngPosition = LBound(relocList) To UBound(relocList)
    Set startingRow = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=relocList(lngPosition), After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not startingRow Is Nothing Then
        Columns(startingRow.Column).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Columns(1).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
     End If
Next lngPosition

Columns(13).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Delete


Dim nextone As String
j = 1
i = 2
            Do Until i = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).Row
            If Cells(i, 8).Value = "Partial Disputed" Then
                Rows(i).Delete
                Else
                i = i + 1
            End If

            If Cells(i, 11).Value = "Deliver" Then Cells(i, 11).Value = "Pledge"
            
            If Cells(i, 1).Value = "PLEDGE" Then
            temporary_row = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 12), Range("J:J"), 0)
            Cells(i, 5) = Cells(temporary_row, 5)
            Cells(i, 8) = Cells(temporary_row, 8)
            End If
Loop

Dim As String
i = 1

'remove blanks

    
   =======================================================================================================================================================
    lastRowNo = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row 
    
    wbmCall.Activate
    Sheets("AcadiaFeeds").Select
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.FilterMode = False 'gdyby komus wpadl do lepetyny glupi pomysl dodawania filtra w Acadia Feeds
    
    srchRowNo = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row + 5
    If srchRowNo < 10 Then
        srchRowNo = 10 
        lastrow_preupload = 10
    End If
    Range("L" & srchRowNo).Value = "Uploaded " & Format(Now, "mmm dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss") & " by " & LCase(Environ("USERNAME"))
    srcRowNo = 1
    i = 1
    

 
    
    Do Until i > lastRowNo
        Range("A" & srchRowNo & ":K" & srchRowNo).Value = wbResults.Sheets(1).Range("A" & srcRowNo & ":K" & srcRowNo).Value
        srchRowNo = srchRowNo + 1
        srcRowNo = srcRowNo + 1
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    wbResults.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set wbResults = Nothing
    wbmCall.Activate
    Set wbmCall = Nothing
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Calls").Select

    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        customView = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActiveWorkbook.CustomViews.Add ViewName:="doAcadii", RowColSettings:=True
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AcadiaFeeds").Select
    callClmn = 5 'Our Unique Agreement Identifier na sztywno
    cTypeClmn = 9 'call type na sztywno w kolumnie 5tej
    
    
=======================================================================================================================================================
    
backAtLoop:

    srchRowNo = lastrow_preupload

    lastrow_updated = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Do Until srchRowNo = lastrow_updated + 1
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AcadiaFeeds").Select
    
    srchRowNo = srchRowNo + 1

        amp = Cells(srchRowNo, callClmn + 5).Value ' amp ID
        
        srchString = Cells(srchRowNo, callClmn).Value 'od dolu bierze unique identifier
        
        callAmt = Cells(srchRowNo, callClmn + 1).Value 'amt called
        
        cType = Cells(srchRowNo, cTypeClmn).Value 'call type
        
        quantity = Cells(srchRowNo, callClmn - 1).Value 'ilosc papierow
        
        state = Cells(srchRowNo, callClmn + 3).Value 'business state pledge accepted
        
        delivery_type = Cells(srchRowNo, callClmn + 6)
        
        typ = Cells(srchRowNo, 1).Value 'margin_call lub pledge
        If Cells(srchRowNo, callClmn - 3).Value <> "CASH" Then
            asset = Cells(srchRowNo, callClmn - 3).Value ' aktywo
            Else:
            asset = Cells(srchRowNo, callClmn - 2).Value
        End If
        
        Sheets("Calls").Select
        Set foundmatchx = Columns(srchRange).Find(What:=srchString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False)
        If typ = "MARGIN_CALL" Then
    
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(srchRange), srchString) = 0 Then 'sprawdza dany agreement jest w mcalls table
                Sheets("AcadiaFeeds").Select
                notFound = notFound & "; " & srchString
                Range("A" & srchRowNo & ":I" & srchRowNo).Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 65535
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
                Range("K" & srchRowNo).Value = "Not Found"
            ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(srchRange), srchString) <> 0 Then 
                'howMany = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(srchRange), srchString)
                 
                
                foundmatchx.offset(0, 3).Activate ' aktywuje offset AMT called
                
                If ActiveCell.offset(0, 11) = "Initial" And cType = "Initial" Then 'idk nor care
                
                'nowt to do here
                
                ElseIf cType = "Initial" And Right(srchString, 4) <> "FBCO" Then
                
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AcadiaFeeds").Select 'acadia feeds
                    Range("A" & srchRowNo & ":E" & srchRowNo).Select
                    With Selection.Interior
                        .Pattern = xlSolid
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = 49407
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                    Range("F" & srchRowNo).Value = "IM call not found"
                GoTo nexxtSrchRowNo
                
                ElseIf cType = "Initial" And Right(srchString, 4) = "FBCO" Then
                
                'nowt to do here
                
                Else
                
                Columns(srchRange).FindNext(foundmatchx).offset(0, 3).Activate 
                
                End If
                Range("J" & srchRowNo).Value = "Already Loaded", Range("A" & srchRowNo & ":I" & srchRowNo).Select
                
                If ActiveCell.Value = callAmt Then 
                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AcadiaFeeds").Select 'acadia feeds
                    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AcadiaFeeds").Range("A" & srchRowNo & ":I" & srchRowNo).Interior
                    
                        .Pattern = xlSolid
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = 5296274
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                    Range("K" & srchRowNo).Value = "Already Loaded"
                ElseIf ActiveCell.Value <> "" And ActiveCell.Value <> callAmt Then 
                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AcadiaFeeds").Select 'acadia feeds
                    Range("A" & srchRowNo & ":E" & srchRowNo).Select
                    With Selection.Interior
                        .Pattern = xlSolid
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = 49407
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                    Range("K" & srchRowNo).Value = "Loaded w/ different amt - please investigate"
                    amntReplaced = True 
                Else
                    ActiveCell.Value = callAmt 
                    ActiveCell.offset(0, 20).Value = "loaded from AcadiaFeeds sheet row# " & srchRowNo
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "Something unexpected happend"
            End If
nexxtSrchRowNo:
        End If
            
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AcadiaFeeds").Select
        If typ = "PLEDGE" Then
        
            Sheets("Calls").Select 'calls
            wiersz = foundmatchx.Row
        
        
            If IsVarArrayEmpty(amp_array) = False Then
                j = 1
                loaded = "not_loaded"
                For j = 1 To UBound(amp_array)
                    If amp_array(j, 1) = amp Then
                       loaded = "already_loaded"
                       j = UBound(amp_array)
                    End If
                
                Next
            Else: loaded = "not_loaded"
            End If
                
        Select Case loaded
                
            Case "already_loaded"
                 If state = "Pledge Accepted" Then
                     If IsEmpty(Cells(wiersz, quantity_column)) = False And quantity <> Cells(wiersz, quantity_column) Then
                     
                        Application.Union(Range(Cells(wiersz + 1, srchRange - 2), Cells(wiersz + 1, srchRange - 1)), Range(Cells(wiersz + 1, srchRange + 1), Cells(wiersz + 1, srchRange + 2))).Style = "Good"
                     
                     Else:

                        Application.Union(Range(Cells(wiersz, srchRange - 2), Cells(wiersz, srchRange - 1)), Range(Cells(wiersz, srchRange + 1), Cells(wiersz, srchRange + 2))).Style = "Good"

                     End If
                 
                 
                 End If
                 
            Case "not_loaded"
            
            If delivery_type = Cells(wiersz, direction_column) And IsEmpty(Cells(wiersz, quantity_column)) = True Then
            
                 If state = "Pledge Accepted" Then
                     Application.Union(Range(Cells(wiersz, srchRange - 2), Cells(wiersz, srchRange - 1)), Range(Cells(wiersz, srchRange + 1), Cells(wiersz, srchRange + 2))).Style = "Good"
                 End If
    
                Cells(wiersz, quantity_column) = quantity
                Cells(wiersz, asset_column) = asset
                
               
            ElseIf delivery_type = Cells(wiersz, direction_column) And IsEmpty(Cells(wiersz, quantity_column)) = False Then
            
                 Cells(wiersz, quantity_column).Select
                 Call MainModule.insertRow
                 Cells(wiersz + 1, quantity_column) = quantity
                 Cells(wiersz + 1, asset_column) = asset
                 If state = "Pledge Accepted" Then
                     Application.Union(Range(Cells(wiersz + 1, srchRange - 2), Cells(wiersz + 1, srchRange - 1)), Range(Cells(wiersz + 1, srchRange + 1), Cells(wiersz + 1, srchRange + 2))).Style = "Good"
                 End If
            
                
            ElseIf delivery_type <> Cells(wiersz, direction_column) Then
            
                howMany = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(srchRange), srchString)
                
                i = 1
                
                For i = 1 To howMany
                
                Set foundmatchx = Columns(srchRange).FindNext(foundmatchx)
                'daje find dla danego agreeementu
                    temporary_row = foundmatchx.Row
                    
                    If delivery_type = Cells(temporary_row, direction_column) And IsEmpty(Cells(temporary_row, quantity_column)) = True Then
                        '1_17 change
                        If state = "Pledge Accepted" Then
                            Application.Union(Range(Cells(temporary_row, srchRange - 2), Cells(temporary_row, srchRange - 1)), Range(Cells(temporary_row, srchRange + 1), Cells(temporary_row, srchRange + 2))).Style = "Good"
                        End If
                    
                        Cells(temporary_row, quantity_column) = quantity
                        Cells(temporary_row, asset_column) = asset
                        i = howMany
                    End If
                Next
                
             End If

         End Select
        End If
         
        Loop
   
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Calls").Select
        'aplikuje filtr spowrotem
        If customView = True Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            With ActiveWorkbook.CustomViews("doAcadii")
                .Show
                .Delete
            End With
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
        'ponizsze IF dodane 07/30
        
        If amntReplaced = True Then
        
        MsgBox "Acadia extract uploaded, but some calls were loaded with different call amounts." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please investigate for issues before saving this spreadsheet."
        
        Else
        
        MsgBox "Acadia extract uploaded!"

    End If


End Sub
Sub amtsCalled()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim relocList() As Variant
Dim lngPosition As Integer
Dim startingRow As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim temporary_row As Integer

wbmCall.Activate

    Sheets("AcadiaFeeds").Select
    
    Dim amp_array()

    Cells(Range("J65536").End(xlUp).Row, 10).Select 'last row
    MsgBox (Cells(Range("J65536").End(xlUp).Row, 10))
    amp_array = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp))

wbResults.Activate

relocList = Array("Margin Call Amp ID", "Amp ID", "Call Type", "Business State", "Valuation Date", "Total Call Amount", "Our Unique Agreement Identifier", "Quantity", "FX Currency", "Security Id", "Type")
Stop
For lngPosition = LBound(relocList) To UBound(relocList)
    Set startingRow = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=relocList(lngPosition), After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not startingRow Is Nothing Then
        Columns(startingRow.Column).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Columns(1).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
     End If
Next lngPosition

Columns(12).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Delete


Dim nextone As String

i = 2
Do Until i = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).Row
    For j = 1 To UBound(amp_array)
        If Cells(i, 10).Value = amp_array(j, 1) Then GoTo nextone
        
    Next
    
            If Cells(i, 8).Value = "Partial Disputed" Then
            Rows(i).Delete
            Else
            i = i + 1
            End If
            
            
            If Cells(i, 1).Value = "PLEDGE" Then
            temporary_row = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 11), Range("J:J"), 0)
            Cells(i, 5) = Cells(temporary_row, 5)
            End If
nextone:
    
Loop


'remove blanks

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub ss()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function IsVarArrayEmpty(anArray As Variant)

Dim i As Integer

On Error Resume Next
    i = UBound(anArray, 1)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    IsVarArrayEmpty = False
Else
    IsVarArrayEmpty = True
End If

End Function
```

Some of the lines are in Polish, is this causing the issue with uploading new macros and working when it's unshared?

Comment: Please explain what *"does not work anymore"* exactly means. Please provide a [mcve] of the actual issue instead of your entire code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is by design:

*"Once you share a workbook, any Visual Basic project it contains is no longer accessible. Excel can’t deal with multiple users editing the same macros, so it simply prevents changes to those macros. You can’t record new macros, either. However, you can run macros from shared workbooks."*

Ref: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-excel-with/0596007663/ch08s03.html